# If statement to change consecutive data values

Tags: excel, vba

i have bunch of random data sets of 1, 2 and 3s in a column. e.g.

```
1
1
1
2
3
1
3
3
3
3
3
2
1
```

i want to do an if statement if there are consecutive 2 or 3 e.g. 22 or 333, i want to change them to 1.

i tried to approach the question with an if statement of if cell (i,1) = (i+1,1) then using a for loop as the data set is huge

but the problem in that code is that it does not deal with odd numbers of consecutive, if i use that code and change a 3 consecutive, it will leave the third data unchanged where i want to change it to 1 instead.

does anyone know how to approach this? Im doing this in excel VBA by the way

Comment: To the specific problem you pointed you can save the digit you replaced with one and compare the next one to the saved, if it's the same remove it otherwise keep and continue.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim k As Integer, cnt As Integer
    Dim i As Long, n As Long

    vDB = Range("a1", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    k = vDB(1, 1)

    For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        If k = vDB(i, 1) Then
            If vDB(i, 1) = 2 Or vDB(i, 1) = 3 Then
                cnt = cnt + 1
                If i = UBound(vDB, 1) Then
                    n = n + 1
                    ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
                    If cnt = 0 Then
                        vR(n) = vDB(i, 1)
                    Else
                        vR(n) = 1
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
                vR(n) = vDB(i, 1)
            End If
        Else
            If cnt = 0 Then
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
                vR(n) = k
            Else
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
                vR(n) = 1
                cnt = 0
            End If
            k = vDB(i, 1)
            If i = UBound(vDB, 1) Then
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
                If cnt = 0 Then
                    vR(n) = vDB(i, 1)
                Else
                    vR(n) = 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Range("d1").CurrentRegion.Clear
    Range("d1").Resize(n) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
End Sub
```

### Image

[image]

Comment: I don't like to write one-to-one in a cell. Except when it's not inevitable.
The execution speed becomes slow. When trying to get results, I try to get them as arrays as possible. Why? Because it is fast. We want to draw simple results in an array. Why? When the amount of data is large and the resulting data is not small, the execution speed becomes a problem.
So, I write code on the assumption that there is a lot of data, regardless of the size of the data. The execution speed is immediately apparent as the amount of data is large.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following successfully tested code:

```
Sub replaceConsecutives()

    '===================================================================================
    '   Set the target sheet and column ---> set these based on your information
    '===================================================================================

    'Set sheet
    Dim targetSheet As Object 'The sheet at which the original data are written
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    'Set columns
    Const targetCol As Integer = 1 'The column at which the original data are written
    Const finalCol As Integer = 3 'The column at which the modified values will be written

    'Clear the finalCol (in case that there are some data from the previous runs)
    targetSheet.Columns(finalCol).ClearContents

    '===================================================================================
    '   Loop over and replace consecutive values
    '===================================================================================

    'Find the last row in the target column
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = targetSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, targetCol).End(xlUp).row

    'Loop over
    Dim i As Integer 'counts the row number at the finalColumn
    i = 1
    Dim row As Integer
    row = 1
    Do Until Len(targetSheet.Cells(row, targetCol).Text) = 0

        'Read the value at row number "row"
        Dim val As Integer
        val = targetSheet.Cells(row, targetCol).Value

        'Is it greater than 1?
        If val = 1 Then 'No

            targetSheet.Cells(i, finalCol).Value = val

            'Update row
            row = row + 1

            'Update i
            i = i + 1

        Else 'Yes

            'Move forward to reach to the first cell with a different value
            Dim row2 As Integer
            row2 = row + 1
            Do While row2 <= lastRow And targetSheet.Cells(row2, targetCol).Value = val

                row2 = row2 + 1
            Loop

            'Decrease row2 by 1
            row2 = row2 - 1

            'How many duplicates fount?
            If row2 = row Then 'no duplicates found

                targetSheet.Cells(i, finalCol).Value = val

            Else 'at least one duplicate value found

                targetSheet.Cells(i, finalCol).Value = 1
            End If

            'Update row
            row = row2 + 1

            'Update i
            i = i + 1
        End If


    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code gets the same result as my code. The approach is similar. However, your limit is how you type directly into the cell. It is more effective if you write in an array instead of typing it directly into a cell and then put it in a cell.

Comment: Hi @Dy.Lee. Thank you for your vote on my answer usefulness. I ran your code as well. That sounds good. Honestly, I am actually a C++ programmer and hence **speed** and **memory usage** are always two of my main concerns. Although your code yields same results, but I've used fewer memory, fewer variables, no variant variable, and hence my code speeds up the process. Your code sounds great as well, but it's better to declare variable types exactly (i.e., no variant variable) and avoid using arrays with a variable size. I'll be happy to know your opinion.

Comment: I agree with your code, but there are some other unique excel vba specialties in c++ or other language of the porogram. I'm not sure about other languages, but I think users of other languages also have some immatureness with Excel vba. I would advise on that.